# Convert a complex array of array to a list

Tags: python, arrays, list

I have a complex structure array:

```
t=[[[array([x1,y1,z1,i1,r1,g1,b1]),label1,ind1,dist1],
    [array([x2,y2,z2,i2,r2,g2,b2]),label1,ind2,dist2],
    [array([x3,y3,z3,i3,r3,g3,b3]),label1,ind3,dist3]],
   [[array([x4,y4,z4,i4,r4,g4,b4]),label2,ind4,dist4],
   [array([x5,y5,z5,i5,r5,g5,b5]),label2,ind5,dist5]]]
```

that I want to convert like that:

```
t=[[array([x1,y1,z1,i1,r1,g1,b1]),label1,ind1,dist1,
    array([x2,y2,z2,i2,r2,g2,b2]),label1,ind2,dist2,
    array([x3,y3,z3,i3,r3,g3,b3]),label1,ind3,dist3],
   [array([x4,y4,z4,i4,r4,g4,b4]),label2,ind4,dist4,
    array([x5,y5,z5,i5,r5,g5,b5]),label2,ind5,dist5]]
```

I have already tried:

```
t.tolist()
```

but it doesn't work...

Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just chain one level with  [itertools.chain](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain):

```
t=[[[array(["x1","y1","z1","i1","r1","g1","b1"]),"label1","ind1","dist1"],
    [array(["x2","y2","z2","i2","r2","g2","b2"]),"label1","ind2","dist2"],
    [array(['x3','y3','z3','i3','r3','g3','b3']),'label1','ind3','dist3']],
   [[array(['x4','y4','z4','i4','r4','g4','b4']),'label2','ind4','dist4'],
   [array(['x5','y5','z5','i5','r5','g5','b5']),'label2','ind5','dist5']]]


from itertools import chain
t[:] = (list(chain.from_iterable(ele)) for ele in t)



from pprint import pprint as pp

pp(t)
```

Which removes one level:

```
[[array(['x1', 'y1', 'z1', 'i1', 'r1', 'g1', 'b1'], 
      dtype='<U2'),
  'label1',
  'ind1',
  'dist1',
  array(['x2', 'y2', 'z2', 'i2', 'r2', 'g2', 'b2'], 
      dtype='<U2'),
  'label1',
  'ind2',
  'dist2',
  array(['x3', 'y3', 'z3', 'i3', 'r3', 'g3', 'b3'], 
      dtype='<U2'),
  'label1',
  'ind3',
  'dist3'],
 [array(['x4', 'y4', 'z4', 'i4', 'r4', 'g4', 'b4'], 
      dtype='<U2'),
  'label2',
  'ind4',
  'dist4',
  array(['x5', 'y5', 'z5', 'i5', 'r5', 'g5', 'b5'], 
      dtype='<U2'),
  'label2',
  'ind5',
  'dist5']]
```

If it is an actual `array.array` the logic is the same

Answer (score 1):

It is not a general solution but it should work in this case:

```
>>> t = [[[array([1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]), 1, 1, 1],
          [array([2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2]), 1, 2, 2],
          [array([3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3]), 1, 3, 3]],
         [[array([4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4]), 2, 4, 4],
          [array([5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5]), 2, 5, 5]]]

>>> newt = [[k for subsubt in subt for k in subsubt] for subt in t]

>>> print newt
[[array([1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]),
  1,
  1,
  1,
  array([2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2]),
  1,
  2,
  2,
  array([3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3]),
  1,
  3,
  3],
 [array([4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4]),
  2,
  4,
  4,
  array([5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5]),
  2,
  5,
  5]]
```

Note: I replaced the values in your list to make it reproducible.